# “ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis”

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

i have 9 different series that i am trying to concat in pandas

code below:

```
retail = pd.concat([aapl, bud, csco, dis, mcd, nflx, nvda, pfe, wmt], axis=1)
retail.columns = ['aapl', 'bud', 'csco', 'dis', 'mcd', 'nflx', 'nvda','pfe', 'wmt']
```

but getting error
“ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis”

where am i going wrong?

screenshot of my series attached
it has one index timestamp and 1 column adjusted_close
[image]

Comment: you have some ticker have same date more than one time

Answer (score 0):

When you concatenate with `axis=1` it's throwing an error because your dfs share index values. You can use `ignore_index=True` although it is prone dropping data if your dfs don't match up perfectly. I recommend adding another column for each df to store the corp name and then concatenate using axis=0 which is the default.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

appl_data = {'date': {0: Timestamp('2022-01-02 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2022-01-03 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2022-01-04 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2023-01-05 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2024-01-06 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2024-01-07 00:00:00')},
 'adjusted_close': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 2.0}}

appl = pd.DataFrame(appl_data)
appl.set_index('date', inplace=True, drop=True)
appl['corp'] = 'appl'

nflx_data = {'date': {0: Timestamp('2022-01-02 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2022-01-03 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2022-01-04 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2023-01-05 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2024-01-06 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2024-01-07 00:00:00')},
 'adjusted_close': {0: 3, 1: 5, 2: 6, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 9}}

nflx = pd.DataFrame(nflx_data)
nflx.set_index('date', inplace=True, drop=True)
nflx['corp'] = 'nflx'

cat = pd.concat([appl, nflx])
```

Output:

```
     adjusted_close corp
date        
2022-01-02  1.0     appl
2022-01-03  2.0     appl
2022-01-04  3.0     appl
2023-01-05  1.0     appl
2024-01-06  1.0     appl
2024-01-07  2.0     appl
2022-01-02  3.0     nflx
2022-01-03  5.0     nflx
2022-01-04  6.0     nflx
2023-01-05  1.0     nflx
2024-01-06  1.0     nflx
2024-01-07  9.0     nflx
```